# Why can't I get facebook ad-group stats using the api?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I am trying to extract stats from ad groups using the facebook-ads python package by applying the "get_conversion_stats" method to an AdGroup object (class 'facebookads.objects.AdGroup').

```
accounts = me.get_ad_accounts(fields=['name', 'account_status'])
accounts_list = list(accounts)
for accounti in accounts_list:
campaign = accounti.get_ad_campaigns(fields=[facebookads.objects.AdCampaign.Field.name])
campaign_list = list(campaign)
for campaigni in campaign_list:
    adset = campaigni.get_ad_sets(fields=["name"])
    adset_list = list(adset)
    for adseti in adset_list:
        adgroups = adseti.get_ad_groups()
        adgroups_list = list(adgroups)
        for adgroupi in adgroups_list:
            adgroup = AdGroup(str(adgroupi["id"]))
            adgroup.remote_read(fields=[AdGroup.Field.name, AdGroup.Field.campaign_id])
            adgroup_conv = accounti.get_ad_group_conversion_stats()
            print accounti["name"]+", "+campaigni["name"]+", "+adseti["name"]+", "+str(adgroupi["id"])
```

I get the following Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\facebookads\objects.py", line 1283, in get_conversion_stats
return self.edge_object(ConversionStats, fields, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\facebookads\objects.py", line 708, in edge_object
    params=params
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\facebookads\objects.py", line 96, in __next__
if not self._queue and not self.load_next_page():
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\facebookads\objects.py", line 125, in load_next_page
for json_obj in response['data']:
KeyError: 'data'
```

The documentation for this object and method can be found here:
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-ads-sdk/blob/master/facebookads/objects.py

I can't figure out what's wrong, and I'd appreciate any help you can give me.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the relevant part on your code which outputs the error, that way we can help you faster!!!

Comment: That's pretty much it.
I got an account object and extracted from it a campaign object and so forth with adset and adgroup.

once I got an adgroup object that contains the id of the object I used this:
adgroup.get_conversion_stats()

and got an error.

Comment: After a second thought, I guess you're right, I added the code.

Comment: Does it work when you call the API directly? that 'Ads' SDK has wrappers which insulate you from the actual API calls being made and it doesn't look like it returns the underlying exception if the call fails which makes it difficult to debug where the problem is if you're not familiar with the API